# Featured question does not remove after gave the bounty

Tags: bug, featured-questions

Today I got an issue (I am not 100% sure it is an issue). Featured question does not remove from after given the bounty.

I have added a bounty for this question: *[Why does TypeScript accept a value as a data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560995/why-does-typescript-accept-a-value-as-a-data-type)*

Today is the end date for that bounty. So I just searched for the `angular` keyword in the search box and went to the featured question and gave the bounty to an answer. Then I went to the search box and clicked the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button with the `angular` keyword as same as which is I already entered in the search text box (I also tried a hard refresh). Now the bounty has been removed, but it does not remove the question from the feature option.

I have attached the screenshot below for the reference.

[image]

Comment: Caching probably.

Comment: *Also tried hard refresh* won't clear Server Caching...

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: How long after awarding the bounty were you still able to see the question in the "Featured" list? 5 seconds? 1 minute? 10 minutes? 2 hours? 24 hours?

Comment: I don't know sure.. May be around 10 second's

Comment: I'd give it about 15 minutes.  It is probably heavily cached.